# How to pass a reference to UIView instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have a set of "controls" in a `UIView` that are displayed inside a `UITableViewCell` - this includes a `UILabel`, and some UIButtons. When a `UITableViewCell` is pressed, I'm displaying a new view from a different `UIViewController`. I want this view to include the "controls" from the `UITableViewCell` with the buttons/label in the exact same state as before.

What's the correct way to do this? Should I create a model that stores the state of the buttons/label and then access the model or is there an easier way?

Many thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by state?

Comment: The buttons are arrows that can be "pressed" to be changed into a highlighted state, and depending on whether the buttons are pressed or not, the text inside the UILabel changes. So I want the text and highlighted state of buttons to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

If you need that for beautiful transition animation only, it would be better to take a "screenshot" of your `UITableViewCell`. But if they should be interactive as well, just move them to new superview. But you will need to maintain constraints/frames/outlets consistency in both places...

Comment: Yeah they should be interactive as well. But if I take the reference of the `UIView` and add it as a subview of the superview, the text within the `UILabel` reverts to the default value, as if I've added a completely new `UIView`.

Comment: @Tometoyou I checked it right now, if I do `addSubview:` to new superview, `UILabel` state preserves as well as it's text

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm doing it wrong, I'm using this code: `expandedViewController.addControls(cellRect, theControls: cell.controls)` then in the addControls function saying `controls = theControls
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.addSubview(controls)`

Comment: Maybe you have some code that resets it? Could you please try it in new fresh project that do not contain anything else?

Comment: It's kind of hard to move just that part into a fresh project. But I have a feeling it's to do with being within a `UITableViewCell`. When I check what the value of the label is in the original UITableViewCell, it doesn't show the updated value... Yet on screen it shows it.

Comment: I don't mean move exactly that part of project, just create empty project with simple 'tableView' and generate some `UITableViewCell` and try to move the labels to new view controller